# Elements created by getJSON don't react to the rest of the javascript loaded on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, vimeo

I am using getJSON to access Vimeo's Simple API, and any objects created on the page by the call, do not react to the rest of the javascript that is on the page. It is probably something simple that I am missing. Here is my getJSON code:

```
$.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1822727/videos.json", function(data){
     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      var videoID = value.id;
      var videoThm = value.thumbnail_large;
      $('#galThms').prepend('<li id="thm' + videoID + '" style="background-image:url(' + videoThm + ');"><a href="#playVideo"></a></li>');
      console.log(videoThm);
     });
 });
```

Comment: what do you mean by the rest of the javascript on the page? Are you using any event listeners?

Comment: I just mean that later on in the page I have jquery that is accessing the elements that are being created by the getJSON call. For example, the getJSON is creating <li>s and then other jquery is writing info into those <li>s.

Comment: Your getJSON works fine, how are you trying to access those <li>s with jquery?

Comment: Just the standard jquery method: $('#galThms li')

Comment: You must be trying to access those li before they are getting created or you are adding the info in an incorrect way, works fine with what I tested: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/vnU4S/

Comment: You are right. My syntax was wrong and I was accessing them before they were created. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it to work :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but any thoughts on why this won't work in IE 9+. Your fiddle works fine when I test it in BrowserStack, but not my site. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you make sure you included jquery? Also, check with developer tools(F12 in IE) if its throwing an error

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/8t3Xq/1/**

This demonstrates loading your `<li>` thumbs just as your question does, then I show how to easily change one of them.  How to "*change*" them is endless, this is just a simple example of changing the content and background.  So you must not have your selectors right.

This is just a snippet, see fiddle for everything...

```
$.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1822727/videos.json", function(data){
     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      var videoID = value.id;
      var videoThm = value.thumbnail_large;
      $('#galThms').prepend('<li id="thm' + videoID + '" style="background-image:url(' + videoThm + ');"><a href="#playVideo"></a></li>');
      console.log(videoThm);
     });
 });

window.changeIt=function()
{
    $('li').first().html("I'm changed!");
    $('li').first().css("background-image","");
}
```

Just make sure the `<li>`s are present first before your code that changes them is present.  Would need to see more of you code to understand when/how that happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/1822727/videos.json", function(data){
     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
      var videoID = value.id;
      var videoThm = value.thumbnail_large;
      $('#galThms').append('<li id="thm' + videoID + '" style="background-image:url(' + videoThm + ');"><a href="#playVideo"></a></li>');
      console.log(videoThm);
      $( "#galThms li" ).click(function() {
          $(this).hide();
      });
     });
 });
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

there is no way that my answer is so far removed from the problem statement. my guess is that either I somehow errantly posted this answer or the problem was edited. apologies

<strike>you could also use:</strike>

```
$(document).on('click','li .playVideo',function(){
  //do something
});
```

i would probably change your #playVideo to a class, if you will have multiple li's